# Workbench cavity not appearing when rendering animation from command line

Tags: workbench-render-engine

The Cavity feature of the Workbench render engine Properties / Render Properties / Options / Cavity provides the expected results when rendering an animation from the UI Render / Render Animation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F12</kbd>).

Using the command line (ex: `blender -b myfile.blend -a`) on the same file gives a result which seems to completely no cavity.

How can I render a cavity using a command line?